# React native app not running but stops at welcome to Metro

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and i am trying to launch an application created with `yarn start` or `npm start`, but both of this command ends in the screen below, it gets there and does not launch.

[image: Screenshot after i run npm start from my console]

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

`npx react-native start`

or

`npx react-native run-android`

you can change npx by npm

Comment: i think its an environment thing...becos it runs on IOS

Answer (score 0):

I found that it gets stuck there if the port metro uses (8081) is in use (probably from another metro process).

In this case, you just need to kill the other process. Assuming it's using port 8081, here's a one-liner to kill it:

`` sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8081 ``

And then run `npm run start` again